# Facebook Public Post Search API

Tags: facebook, api, post, public

We have been developing on the a software. 
We were using feature Public Post Search API  of Facebook.
However Facebook will be deprecated it at April 30, 2015. Do you have the alternative of this property?
Could we use this feature through Facebook Partners ? 
If there is no such a partnership, would you recommended us to any company?
Could we use the Facebook API search feature with media solution partner program offered by facebook? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> Do you have the alternative of this property?

No

> Could we use this feature through Facebook Partners?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mediasolutions There should be an email there, the bar is probably quite high for partnership

> If there is no such a partnership, would you recommended us to any company?

See previous

> Could we use the Facebook API search feature with media solution partner program offered by Facebook?

No.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I've seen a few sites for this property. For Example: Datasift and Gnip . But They are brings the missing data. Is there any other alternative solutions?